# CSS on alternate layout only loads on page refresh

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby-2.1.2 and rails 4.2.0

I have 2 layouts on my website.

The main one, application.html.erb that is used for most of the website.
The secondary one, emptylayout.html.erb for things that need its own setup (splash pages and tooltips).

If I am making a view that uses the second layout, in the controller I am adding within the view method for that page.

```
render :layout => 'emptylayout'
```

I am running into an issue where if while browsing you switch to a page that uses a different layout then the last page (go from the splash page to pretty much any other page on the website). The first time it loads it will not be styled correctly. If you refresh everything works.
I am not sure what code snippets would help in this case.
You can see this in action here http://swtordata.com/ and clicking any link other then "other swtor tools" or "sign in with google"

Comment: not sure if this is related, but there is an error in the javascript `"function" == typeof changeswtorcartel() && changeswtorcartel()` looks like it should be `"function" == typeof changeswtorcartel && changeswtorcartel()` maybe? (though, if this is being minified incorrectly that may not be the thing to update specifically)

Comment: It doesn't look the page actually navigates - is it using some other mechanism (single page app-like) to show different pages?

Comment: can you share the code for each layout please

Comment: I think the problem is related to turbolinks. Disable turbolinks and see what happens.

Comment: Removing turbolinks fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't proposing disabling turbolinks as a solution but it works for you, it's fine. This shows that there is a problem in your javascript code. Are you using the `$.ready` for initialization? You should switch to `page:change` event when using turbolinks.